# How to get last executed query in Django when DEBUG is False?

Tags: django, logging

I would like to log the last executed db query when an exception occurs. Obviously `DEBUG = False`. The below code does not work, `connection.queries` returns `[]`.

```
try:
    MyModel2.objects.all()
    MyModel2.objects.all()
    Boom
except:
    from django.db import connection
    logger.exception("SQL: %s", connection.queries)
```

Output:

> "SQL: []"

The code is running on Celery and as web application (uwsgi).

Comment: You say "obviously DEBUG = False", but "connection.queries is only available if DEBUG is True" per [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/models/) - could you go into a bit more detail about why it is obvious?

Comment: Ok, so: How to get last executed query (or all queries) on production (DEBUG is False). Sentry does that somehow.